# Specifying the Stroke Alignment for an SVG Circle?

Tags: html, css, svg

This demo has an SVG circle with a stroke.  The `stroke-alignment` property has been set to `outer`, but the stroke still overlaps the fill of the circle.

How to we get the stroke to position itself to the outside of the circle?

```html
<body>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      viewBox="0 0 240 240"
      height="240"
      width="240"
    >
      <defs><!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={}--></defs>
      <circle
        cx="120"
        cy="120"
        r="100"
        fill="blue"
        fill-opacity="1"
        stroke="red"
        stroke-opacity="0.5"
        stroke-width="40"
        ,
        stroke-alignment="outer"
      ></circle>
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be supported at all unfortunately https://caniuse.com/?search=stroke-align

Comment: ... Very delicous name ... That would explain why most of the documentation on it is ... abstract ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `stroke-alignment` is not supprted (yet?).
But you might do something like this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 240 240" height="240" width="240">          
  <circle
    cx="120"
    cy="120"
    r="120"
    fill="#f007"
  />
  <circle
    cx="120"
    cy="120"
    r="100"
    fill="blue"
  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the fill is opaque, you can also use the [`paint-order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) CSS property/presentation attribute. The position of the stroke remains unchanged, but the inner half that overlaps the fill gets hidden behind it. So to achieve a visible stroke width of 20, you need to actually set `stroke-width="40"`.

For a partially transparent fill, the inner half of the stroke shines through.

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  viewBox="0 0 500 240"
  height="240"
  width="240"
>
  <circle
    cx="120"
    cy="120"
    r="100"
    fill="blue"
    fill-opacity="1"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-opacity="0.5"
    stroke-width="40"
    paint-order="stroke fill"
  ></circle>
  <circle
    cx="380"
    cy="120"
    r="100"
    fill="blue"
    fill-opacity="0.5"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-opacity="1"
    stroke-width="40"
    paint-order="stroke fill"
  ></circle>
</svg>
```